# How to Compare two string stored in variables in Perl?

Tags: regex, string, perl

I want to check if $test1 is present in $test2 and $test3.

I tried with the following code but I am not getting the correct output.

```
my $test1 = "cat";
my $test2 = "My name is cat";
my $test3 = "My name is apple";

if($test2  eq /$test1/){
    print "yes2\n";
}

if($test3 eq /$test1/){
   print "yes3\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To match a regex use `=~` operator:

```
if($test2  =~ /$test1/){
    print "yes2\n";
}

if($test3 =~ /$test1/){
   print "yes3\n";
}
```

You could use word boundaries to match exactly, to avoid matching `caterpillar`:

```
if($test2  =~ /\b$test1\b/){
    print "yes2\n";
}

if($test3 =~ /\b$test1\b/){
   print "yes3\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Its working. Can you elaborate a little on uses of \b.

Comment: @JayeshRanjanMajhi: A word boundary `\b` is a zero-length assertion that match a boundary between a word character and a non-word character. See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: one doubt : how can I mimic this thing  if($test2  =~ /^jayesh/) when using variable

Comment: @JayeshRanjanMajhi: Sorry, I don't get you. What do you mean by `mimic this thing`?

Comment: I want to know how can I modify the regular expression to get output as yes2 only 

my $test1 = "cat";
my $test2 = "My name is cat";
my $test3 = "My name is cat.ball";

if($test2  =~ /$test1/){
    print "yes2\n";
}

if($test3 =~ /$test1/){
   print "yes3\n";
}

Comment: @JayeshRanjanMajhi: Change `/\b$test1\b/` into `/(?:^|\s)$test1(?:\s|$)/` this will match `cat` only if it is surrounded by spaces or at the begining or at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method, not using `if` directly.

```
$result = ($test2  =~ /\b$test1\b/) ? "Matched" : "No Match";
print "$result\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to check a string contained in another one is via a regular expression :

```
print "Found." if ( $test2 ~= /$test1/);
```

in your case, you would even be more concise :

```
foreach $str in ( $test1, $test2 ) {
   print "Found $test1 in $str." if ( $str ~= /$test1/);
}
```

or even, using default assignemnt :

```
foreach ( $test1, $test2 ) {
   print "Found $test1 in $str." if ( /$test1/ );
}
```

The test is checking against `$_`, which is automatically assigned by the foreach clause.